# Pop Up UIView with Countdown Timer

Tags: animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I want to create a simple pop up (which I already have implemented) and a simple countdown which updates the only label in the pop up. I have tried using the `UIViews init()` function but that was not called. I have also tried connecting the `UIViews` label from the `UIViewController` to update it that way but that also did not work. The problem is in that I have no idea how to start the timer and update the label right after the pop up animation is finished.

Comment: How are you showing the pop up?

Comment: @JoséNeto I have the `UIView` in the storyboard and have an outlet to it. in the `viewDidAppear` I call `self.view.addSubview()`

Comment: You need the timer to changes several times or you need just a delay to run the change once?

Comment: I have the timer code working fine. It just does not start. I need it to countdown. once finished terminate the view. and have the `uiviewcontroller` notified of the change

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard, I think you need to add your start timer code in awakeFromNib() of the view:

```
public override func awakeFromNib() {
    // Add timer init and start here
}
```